# Auto clicker is causing a device restart on Galaxy S10

Tags: android, kotlin, mobile-application, mobile-app-testing

Working on an autoclicker with direct UI access through accessability service, and image analysis through mediaprojection and custom analysis code. On my S22 it works as intended and runs indefinitely, but on my S10 it will run for several hours, then the device restarts for no apparent reason.

I've gone through my app logs and added Firebase Crashlytics, but there's nothing showing up on either. Thought maybe I wasn't managing the media projection cleanup correctly, checked everything and can't find anything, the mediaprojection shuts down between uses, restarts when needed via Intent cloning. Accessability nodes are also recycled after I'm done scanning it. One log showed up on the device log after restart, saying the system died and earlier logs will point to the cause. But after the restart Android Studio Logcat doesn't pick up any logs prior to the restart. I've got no experience with taking device bug reports, but is that the only option? And would that reveal the cause?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.